# Manually trigger ajax search in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using select2 plugin with jquery on my website.

It works fine in almost all cases.

I have simple search widget with select2 and remote data search.

When I paste some search query using keybord shortcut, it starts searching.

However, when I am pasting text using mouse, after pasting text nothing happens. I have to for example, add one space to the query to trigger search.

I was thinking about something like:

```
   $(document).on('paste','.select2-search__field', function(){
      // what do here?
   });
```

But I dont know how to trigger search on select2 ver. 4.

Thanks in advance for any solution

Comment: Probably something else is causing this issue. Select2 does work when pasting text using mouse, without any workarounds. Post the actual code or create a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ohnnksku/) (select2 v.4 already imported)

Answer (score -3):

```
$('.select2-search').find('input').trigger('input')
```